Trouble applying the intermediate value theorem to $Ax=e^x$

Show that $Ax=e^x$ has $2$ solutions when $e<A<\infty$ using the intermediate value theorem.

I tried solving this assuming the domain to be $\mathbb{R}$, then letting $f(x)=Ax-e^x$ and evaluating $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ to see if I can get opposite signs to apply the IVT, but this didn't really help.

Where does $e^{x}-Ax$ attain its minimum?

Plotting $y=Ax$, $y=e^x$ on the same graph is also useful to get a senses of where the roots can be (and thus which endpoints to use for IVT).

@JohnOmielan Apologies, that was a mistake of mine while editing from review that wasn't caught before approval. I forgot a \ before the first \infty and I somehow ended up deleting the minus sign in the process. The original question phrasing had both positive and negative $\infty$. I think an edit adding it back would be too minimal for it to be accepted if I submit it, but if you want to add it feel free.

@teadawg1337 Thanks for explaining what happened. You're correct that making just a one-character change won't work for you, but note it's not an issue of your submission not being accepted, but you won't even be allowed to submit it at all (there's a minimum $6$ character change limit which is applied). Since neither the OP nor anybody else has made any additional edits, in particular that include correcting this, I assumed that likely nobody else will in the relatively near future, so I've made the edit myself instead.

Using Bernoulli’s inequality, you get $e^x\geq x+1$, so $e^{x-1}\geq x$, $e^x\geq ex$. Can you get an idea from this?
